# SQL: How to find to the total data size (in bytes) returned from a query?

Tags: mysql, sql

Something like:

```
SUM(*) FROM orders WHERE 'x' = 1;
```

This has to be done from SQL itself, as this will be part of larger query.

The purpose of this is to review the storage size and check on possible savings by deleting obsolete data.

SQL Server has some handy stored procedures for this.  This is MySQL DB, so I'm looking a generic SQL solution as possible, short of that, something for MySql

Comment: Total data size is ambiguous. The total number of Rows? The sum total of an order field? The total disk space being used for a database?

Comment: @RPM: I thought it was the total size of the resultset, in bytes... reading again (especially the title), I still think that's correct no?

Comment: @eggyal, yes total size of the result set.  Also, it doesn't have to be exact.  An approximation will do.

Answer (score 3):

Why not use count?

```
SELECT count(*) FROM orders WHERE 'x' =1
```

Alternatively, you can use the information schema table:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME ,
       (DATA_LENGTH/ 1024) AS "Data Length in MB",
       (INDEX_LENGTH / 1024) AS "Index Length in MB"
       FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
       WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'YOUR DATABASE NAME' 
       AND
       TABLE_NAME = 'YOUR TABLE NAME';
```

Where `'YOUR DATABASE NAME'` is your database's name, and `'YOUR TABLE NAME'` is the table you need to know data about.

Comment: That will give you only the row count, not the total data.

Comment: Exactly. And the row count is an approximation of the of the result set size. as the OP wants.

Comment: As the OP, I would like to have data size in bytes.  I guess I should have mentioned bytes.  In any case, each row can vary widely in the amount of data they return, so even something  like "data_size = row_count * average_row_size" would be too far off the mark to be usable.

Comment: @Jahmic, my edit above will give you the information you are looking for, I think.  But it may be easier just to go into a tool like PHPMYADMIN and search around on the INFORMATION_SCHEMA to get a feeling for the data.

Comment: Getting better, but your edit will show the total size of the table, while the query will only return part of the query.  PHPMyAdmin won't be use either as this will be part of larger query being run inside another script.

Comment: I ran this and compared the results along size the table size presented in Sequel Pro, and it appears that `DATA_LENGTH` and `INDEX_LENGTH` are in bytes, and therefore need be divided by 1048576, not 1024.